# What are the jqplot default series colors?

Tags: jqplot

I'm plotting some data on a jqPlot pie chart, and would like to get at the slice colors.

- I'm aware of the possibility to set the slices to colors I set myself. I want to avoid this because the default colors contrast nicely from one to the next slice. Also, the slices highlight on mouse-over, and these highlight-colors are also good looking in the whole. It seems too much work to create a whole new color-scheme and then apply it to the plot when jqPlot already has a good thing built in.
- I want to get at the slice colors, because I need to give additional information on certain slices, and will do this outside the plot. Re-using the slice colors would additionally allow me to forego using a legend in the plot itself, and creating my own table with "slice color - name - additional information" which then serves both as legend and source of additional information.

Is there a source of the default colors somewhere? Or is there a way to programmatically extract them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, managed to find it by delving in the actual code, as the info in the documentation on the website of jqPlot is out of date on this.

For other people wanting to get the default colors:

- jquery.jqplot.js, line 354:  defaultColors: [ "#4bb2c5", "#EAA228", "#c5b47f", "#579575", "#839557", "#958c12", "#953579", "#4b5de4", "#d8b83f", "#ff5800", "#0085cc", "#c747a3", "#cddf54", "#FBD178", "#26B4E3", "#bd70c7"]
- jquery.jqplot.js, line 355: defaultNegativeColors: [ "#498991", "#C08840", "#9F9274", "#546D61", "#646C4A", "#6F6621", "#6E3F5F", "#4F64B0", "#A89050", "#C45923", "#187399", "#945381", "#959E5C", "#C7AF7B", "#478396", "#907294"]
- The highlight colors are generated automatically in the function $.jqplot.computeHighlightColors (line 3775 of jquery.jqplot.js). I haven't deduced the actual highlight colors as I don't need them for my purposes, but if anyone else is looking for them, that's where you can start from.

(Line numbers based on version 1.0.8, revision 1250.)

As far as I can tell & also according to the documentation, when the array is exhausted, the colors starts over from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

According to Gimp colorpicker, jqPlot default series colors used in [this example](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php) are - clockwise from orange to blue :

- #eaa228 - (#efbc67 if highlighted),
- #c5b47f   - (#d5c9a4 if highlighted),
- #579575 - (#88b39d if highlighted),
- #839557 - (#a7b388 if highlighted),
- #958c12 - (#b3ad58 if highlighted),
- #4bb2c5 - (#80c8d5 if highlighted).

Hope it will help you.

**EDIT** : Please see in [this link](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html) default series colors specified by jqplot

Comment: Thanks, this is a great start. I could let jqPlot create a piechart with all slices at 5% and then pick up the whole series of colors this way, I guess. However, I was hoping for a less work-intensive solution...

Comment: Please see my edit and [this link](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html) : where default colors of jqplot are specified in seriesColors

Comment: The documentation of jqPlot is out of date. I've ended up looking through the actual code. To my surprise, it's not all that difficult to read, even if you're a jquery/javascript newbie like myself.